# Controlling array fill in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a simple recursive function

```
Z(i,j) = Sum(Z(i, k), k = 0..j-1) + Sum(Z(k, j), k = 0..i-1) 
Z(0,0) = 1
```

If you lay this out in a table, with (0,0) on the bottom left and (i,j) on the top right, you can see that in general, all cells only depend on each of the cells to their left and below, and the top-left to bottom-right diagonals can all be computed in parallel.

For a language like C, I might implement the dynamic programming fill starting from the bottom-left and working my way up the columns:

```
// for Z[n][m] 
for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
 for(j = 0; j <= m; j++) {
  for(k = 0; k < j; k++) {
   Z[i,j] += Z(i, k)
  }
  for(k = 0; k < i; k++) {
   Z[i,j] += Z(k, j)
  }
 }
}
```

If I wanted to parallelize this, I could simply collect the indices of the diagonal that is currently working, and then dispatch the appropriate function on each of the indices.

In Haskell I could do something like:

```
z = array ((0,0), (10,10))
       [((i, j), 1 + (sum (map (\x -> z ! (i, x)) [0..j-1]))  +
                 (sum (map (\x -> z ! (x, j)) [0..i-1]))) | i <- [0..10], j <- [0..10]]
```

There are a couple of things I don't like about this. 1: it is harder to read and less clear what is going on. 2: I have no control over the execution order. How do I know if Haskell is filling the array in the most efficient way possible? Is there a way to implement this in Haskell so that it is both easy to read and I have control over the computational flow?

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.1/docs/Data-Array.html#v:array):

> `array` is strict in the bounds argument and in the indices of the association list, but non-strict in the values.

So your expression will compute only the entries that you actually use. Your `z` is effectively a memo table for the recursive function you specified at the top of your question, and the run-time evaluation order is naturally controlled by the data dependencies in your code work out. In other words, `z ! (i, j)` will be computed efficiently for free, thanks to laziness.

On the question of the readability of your code: I find your functional implementation far more readable than your procedural one. The Haskell code is a lot closer to the specification you gave using the programming language called *maths*: whereas your C code talks about incrementing indexes and accumulating totals, in Haskell you're actually talking about making recursive calls to `z` over a range of values and summing the results. You could use list comprehensions instead of `map` to make it look even more similar to the mathematical notation:

```
z = array ((0,0), (10,10))
       [((i, j), 1 + sum [z ! (i, k) | k <- [0..j-1]]
                   + sum [z ! (k, j) | k <- [0..i-1]]) | i <- [0..10], j <- [0..10]]
```